# Change spinning wheel style from ProgressBar Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `ProgressBar` with the attribute

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

which shows the next spinning wheel:

[image: Spinning wheel from ProgressBar]

But to keep the same style in all my application, I wanted to use, in my `ProgressBar`, the spinning wheel shown on `SwipeRefreshLayout` by default:

[image: Spinning Wheel from SwipeRefreshLayout]

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

---

[ADDED]

I'm looking for the spinning style, its movement and how is it shown. It works something like this:
while turning around, the black "bar" gets longer and then shorter and then again longer and so on,.. changes its size always in the same direction that the bar moves (really difficult to explain how it works, that's why I refered to `SwipeRefreshLayout`'s spinning wheel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this persons progress bar

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1141

you will need to call .Spin() in your code to start it.

Add This to you gradle build file as followed

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
}
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for, Thanks! But I'm getting a problem with that dependence: "Failed to resolve: com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7". What's wrong?

Comment: Have you added compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7' to your gradle build file?

Comment: try
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
}

Comment: I know you may still be having issues but could you please mark this answer as correct as it solves your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the color / style, try this (Android Lollipop + ) :

```
progCircle.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.myXMLColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

More information about PorterDuff [here](https://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/)

Comment: thanks, but is not acually the color what I'm searching. Is how the wheel moves around. I will update the question trying to explain that

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
```

Comment: no, is the same that i have. But really appreciate your anwer :)

Comment: What version of Android are you running on?

Comment: This wont work for pre Android 5.0 devices. Refer to my other answer for styling to those devices

Comment: My phone is  4.1 (API 16), but the App was created to work on every Android after 4.0.3 (API 15)